# Passing multidimensional array to a function (c++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I've been trying to pass a multidimensional array, of an unknown size, to a function, and so far have had no luck, when the array is declared, its dimensions are variables:

```
double a[b][b];
```

As far as I can tell, I need to give the value of b when I declare the function, a can be unknown. I tried declaring b as a global variable, but it then says that it must be a constant.

ie:

```
int b;

double myfunction(array[][b])
{
}

int main()
{
int a;
double c;
double myarray[a][b];

c=myfunction(myarray);

return 0;
}
```

Is there any way get this to work?

Comment: Not very pretty, but can you not just pass in the pointer to the first element?

Comment: `std::vector` makes life so much easier.

Comment: If the dimensions are variable use either `std::vector` or `boost::multiarray`.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you are missing `double` in front of your array parameter. I don't know if this is an oversight in your post here or if it is missing from the code you are compiling as well.

Comment: @chris, `std::vector` makes life easier for single-dimension arrays but it complicates multi-dimension arrays since the size of each row must be set separately.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Yes, but you can work around it pretty easily - a lot more easily than raw arrays. `multiarray` is definitely better if boost is an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing 2D array to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function)

Answer (score 4):

Pass by value :

```
double myfunction(double (*array)[b]) // you still need to tell b
```

Pass by ref :

```
double myfunction(int (&myarray)[a][b]); // you still need to tell a and b
```

Template way :

```
template<int a, int b> double myfunction(int (&myarray)[a][b]); // auto deduction
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps reading some references on C++ and arrays would help,

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pass an array of unknown size you can declare an array in Heap like this

```
//Create your pointer
int **p;
//Assign first dimension
p = new int*[N];
//Assign second dimension
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
p[i] = new int[M];


 than you can declare a function like that: 
double myFunc (**array);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void procedure (int myarray[][3][4])
```

More on this [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)

Comment: I think this is a 3-dimensional array instead of 2, or else you've found a syntax that I've never seen before [which is admittedly possible! :)]

Comment: See Griwes's comment on the other answer. A better link would be [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c).